# change silverlight params value with jquery?

Tags: jquery, silverlight

when i click a image from my html file i want to change silverlight params value (ex. m=sample.wmv) with jquery without refresh page. can i do that?
 

Code is below which i used for silverlight.

`<param name="initparams" value='m=sample.wmv, autostart=false, autohide=false, thumbnail=sample.jpg' />`


thank you very much already now for your help.

Answer (score 0):

No. The InitParams  property on the Silverlight plug-in object must be set prior to the page creating an instance of the object. Write-once during instantiation and read-only at run time.

[MSDN Documentation on InitParams](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc838255%28VS.95%29.aspx)

After instantiation, you can make use of Silverlight's HTML bridge instead.

Comment: Check out the documentation at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645076%28VS.95%29.aspx